# Measuring Doppler and Doppler rate at a receiver

Tags: receiver, digital-modulation, satellite

I am simulating receiving a digital signal, QAM modulation, raised cosine pulses... from a satellite to a receiver on the ground. I wanted to honestly simulate measuring the Doppler and Doppler rate at the receiver.
How is this typically done at a receiver... perhaps a consumer or pro-sumer level device? And what is the "gold standard"...spare no expenses way to do it ?
Thanks!!
Tom

Comment: I'm not native english speaking, and could be misinterpreting this "I wanted to **honestly** simulate". Is there some other meaning to that word?

Comment: I want to accurately simulate... meaning my simulation does a good job representing what goes on in a deployed system.

Comment: Thank you. You got a clear and well formulated question by the way, I'm confident you will get good answers.

Comment: @TomMcGiffen "Simulate measuring" is unclear to me. Are you looking for computer software to run simulations on or some kind of hardware to use to recreate the signal you might receive?

Comment: I am asking how it is done in real hardware. Then I will model that as well as I can in my software.

Answer (score 1):

Low-orbit satellites have fairly slow Doppler rates, making it easier to track. One still needs very stable frequency references inside the receiver downconverter and demodulator if accuracy is needed.

A [Costas demodulator](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66728/demodulation-of-4-qam) is described. The *loop filter* that drives the VCO can have a long time constant as far as Doppler is concerned. This is a Phase-Locked-Loop. You can collect phase corrections to the carrier from this demodulator. Integrating these gives Doppler:

- As the satellite approaches you, phase corrections are in one direction
- As the satellite passes overhead, phase corrections should go to zero.
- As the satellite moves away, phase correction changes direction.

If your receiver chain is off-frequency, when the satellite is overhead, there will be phase corrections taking place. All the oscillators in the receiver affect Doppler.
 COSTAS LOOPS can be built in software or in hardware. In software, an ADC sampling clock is another oscillator that affects Doppler. Stable oscillators are key to accurate Doppler extraction.

Comment: Wow.. thanks for the awesome reply ! I was looking at Costas, but thought it's just for tracking, not getting the actual Doppler/Dop rate.
It is difficult to wait for the sat to go overhead (or to Doppler = 0). 
It looks like I can get the Dop/Dop rate just by monitoring the input to the VCO.For Doppler, this assumes a fairly accurate VCO base frequency (the frequency before any uLF(t) changes). Can you comment on the accuracy of the Doppler, Dop rate in this fashion? Any write up on someone who used such a method on how accurate it can be?
Any other methods beyond Costas ??
Thanks

Comment: *Emergency Locator Transmitter* (ELT) system at 406MHz employs Doppler to locate downed aircraft, from LEO satellites: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2018-2343 .DOP accuracy is 5 km without terrain inputs; its been suggested that this improves to 1km if you know altitude. I've used COSTAS in software using LEO satellites operating at 137 MHz.to extract Doppler. Earth rotation complicates calculating things exactly.

Comment: I went thru that paper. Thanks. It does not give the Doppler equations or error analysis... It states an inaccuracy without giving math details. Or did I miss something ?